# Vue trigger update with custom d3 event

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, vue.js

**tl;dr:** In my [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org) app, I must trigger each of multiple components to update after a property is changed by a [d3](http://d3js.org) event [dispatch](https://github.com/d3/d3-dispatch/blob/master/README.md#dispatch), but only the “final” one reacts.

In my app, there is a `Loc` component containing 23 [d3](http://d3js.org) visualizations in separate `Chart` components, each containing 47 `<a>` tags (data points).

A hover over each `<a>` must trigger a different [Semantic-UI popup](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html)  defined in a `Tip` component.

In sum there should (47 * 23) `Tip` components, but only (47 * 1) are being rendered. Evaluating lifecycle hooks for `Tip` indicates only (47 * 1) are being created and mounted.

It seems even though there are 23 instances of `Chart`, and `renderComplete` is defined in a `data` function, it’s only reacting once.

The pseudo-app looks something like this:

```
<Loc>
  <Chart v-for="..."> <!-- n=23 -->
    <svg :id=uuid></svg>
    <div v-if="renderComplete">
      <Tip v-for="..."> <!-- n1=47 -->
```

Each d3 viz dispatches a custom `completed` event when it finishes rendering.

`Chart` is defined as an extension of `Base`. `Base` contains the definition of `renderComplete` and the event listener:

```
// Base.vue
data() {
 return {
    renderComplete: false
  }
},  
mounted() {
  this.myprop.on('completed.vz',(d)=>{
    this.renderComplete = true
    console.log(this.renderComplete)
  })
}
```

All the visualizations render, but `Tip` components only in `Chart` 23 of 23 are rendered. The first 22 fail. Console output indicates the event is dispatched and the listener executes 23 times. (`renderComplete` is reported `true` 23 times as expected)

I tried making `renderComplete` a `computed`, and also tried putting the `on` declaration in `created`. I’ve also tried numerous iterations of declarations in `Base` and `Chart` but in each case it either doesn’t work or blows up.

Any insight you can provide will be most helpful. Thx!

Comment: is this example similar to your app? http://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/d7c1ujgp/

Comment: Wow Max, nice fiddle! Remarkably similar yes (and working!)  Key diffs might explain probs, e.g., event instead of timeout, data in vuex object, i.e.,`chart = { code : [tips] }`, so `<Tip v-for="tip in chart[code]>`.  i thought the prob might be with the value of `code` but the viz use it correctly. the only thing that doesn't work, ostensibly, is as stated.

Comment: so `<div v-if="renderComplete">` and `<Tip v-for...>` are inside a Chart component(tips passed as props) or you use slot?

Comment: the answer to your question is basically, the former.  In the pseudo block, the 'Chart' component is basically defined as written.  Tip content is accessed from vuex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It's a facepalmer.

The module containing the d3 functions was being loaded with `require`, resulting in a single instance of it.  Using it multiple times resulted in simply resetting its state. Post-processing the first instance of `Chart` on `renderComplete` simply referenced the singleton with state attributes from the final iteration.

To solve the problem, I refactored the `d3chart.js` into an es6 `class`, call with `new`, and no longer bind it in the `component` declaration:

**The old way**

In the `Chart` usage declaration in `Loc`:

```
<component :is="Chart" :myprop="myprop"></component>
```

and in the `Loc` definition:

```
data() {
  return {
    myprop: require('@/viz/d3chart.js')
  }
}
```

**The new way**

```
<component :is="Chart"></component>
```

and

```
import myprop from '@/viz/d3chart.js'
... 
data() {
  return {
    myprop: new myprop()  
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!